# What is the difference between the domain of "f" and the thing that is left of the arrow?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, functions, matrix-equations

I often see functions in my abstract linear algebra class look like this:  $f: S^n\rightarrow R$, and then later I see the following:

$f(X)=X^{1/2}$

$dom(X)=S^n_{++}$

This is confusing to me, since I see $S^n$ as the input to $f$ in the first part, and then I see $dom(X)=S^n_{++}$ as the domain to $f$ immediately after.

What is the difference between the input to $f$ and the $dom$ of $f$ ?  Are people just being sloppy in their notation?

Comment: Usually $f:X\to Y$ implies $X$ is the domain of $f$.   If someone else doesn't use standard notation you might ask them for clarification.  Also $dom(f)$ seems to make more sense that $dom(X)$.  The domain is a set and an input is an element of the domain.

Comment: See [Relation: definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Formal_definition): we may have a difference. A relation $R$  between sets $X$ and $Y$ is a *subset* of the cartesian product $X \times Y$. The *domain* of $R$ is the set of all $x \in X$ such that $xRy$ for some $y \in Y$.

Comment: With this def, we may have that $\text {dom}(R) \subset X$.

Comment: Okay so is that why I see $S^n$ in the equation for $f$, and then I see $S^n_{++}$ in the $dom(X)$?  Because one is a subset of the other?  (by the way, I did not mis-type that).  They really are different.  Although I agree with @JonasMeyer - $dom(f)$ seems more accurate.  Is that maybe a mistake in the textbook?